# selecting the last payment date using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do i grab the last payment using SQL

example:

```
SELECT DATEOFPAYMENT
FROM PAYMENTS
WHERE DATEOFPAYMENT = (SELECT MAX(DATEOFPAYMENT) FROM PAYMENTS)
```

but this doesnt work as it complains asking for group by?

Comment: You want the last payment all over condition or about each person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 DATEOFPAYMENT
FROM PAYMENTS
ORDER BY DATEOFPAYMENT DESC
```

Or to get the whole record:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM PAYMENTS
ORDER BY DATEOFPAYMENT DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATEOFPAYMENT
FROM PAYMENTS
WHERE DATEOFPAYMENT = (SELECT MAX(DATEOFPAYMENT) FROM PAYMENTS GROUP BY DATEOFPAYMENT);
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  The `max()` is unnecessary when you are using the same field for `group by`.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you need a subquery if you want only one field ?

```
select max(DateOfPayment)
FROM Payments
```

If you want all data from "Last payment"

```
select p.Id, p.DateOfPayment, p.Name -- don't know your fields, just an example
FROM Payments p
INNER JOIN (select Id, MAX(DateOfPayment) maxdate
            FROM Payments
            GROUP BY Id) as m
  ON m.Id = p.Id and p.DateOfPayment = m.maxdate
```

if you just want other fields, and have max dateOfPayment by these other fields, all the fields which are not in an aggregation function must be in the GROUP BY clause

```
select p.Id, p.Name, max(p.DateOfPayment)
From Payments p
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Name
```

Comment: For the one field I like the SELECT MAX(FieldName), however I find using TOP and ORDER BY simpler for obtaining other fields in the record.  Is there a reason you would do it this way?

Comment: @Oliver : just an habit : I work with quite different databases (Oracle, Mysql, Sql Server), I try to use ANSI functions as often as I can. LIMIT, TOP, are usually really "Db-specific". MAX is not.

Comment: @Oliver but as said, it's just an habit, no religion ;)

Comment: Ah I see, maybe I have become too comfortable with Microsoft products!!  +1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 DATEOFPAYMENT
FROM PAYMENTS
ORDER BY DATEOFPAYMENT DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

All aggreagete function used by gruop by cluase :

SELECT DATEOFPAYMENT
FROM PAYMENTS
WHERE DATEOFPAYMENT = (SELECT MAX(DATEOFPAYMENT) FROM PAYMENTS group by DATEOFPAYMENT)

Comment: all fields NOT in an aggregated function must be in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options, select the MAX value

```
select max(DateOfPayment) FROM Payments
```

or select the top 1 DateOfPayment order by DateOfPayment desc

run both, check plans and performance and select the best one :)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the last time a payment was made if you just want just that it's just

SELECT MAX(dateofpayment) AS DateOfPAyment FROM Payment

Or for example if you would like a list that give the last time each employee was paid you would use

SELECT MAX(dateofpayment) FROM Payment GROUP BY EmployeeID

The reason you are being asked for a group by is because you are using a aggregate function